# Why must we count in order with Cantor’s diagonal proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have an infinite long list of irrational numbers, and we wish to count them, why must we count 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 …

Why can we not count by skipping numbers? The idea is only to pair every irrational number with a natural number. Think injection not bijection.

For example in row n we use the first n digits past the first significant digit of the irrational.

Here we have an infinite list of irrational numbers and every number is paired with a natural number. Our condition is satisfied.

Pair 1 to 0.1414213562373095…

Pair 17 to 0.1732050807568877…

Pair 223 to 0.223606797749979…

Pair 2449 to 0.2449489742783178…

Pair 26457 to 0.02645751311064591…

…

Our diagonal is 0.17397… we can change it to 0.76776… which can't be on the list. But we can pair 7 to 0.76776…

Or we can change it to 0.33433… which can't be on the list. But we can pair 33 to 0.33433…

Or we can change it to 0.21111… which can't be on the list. But we can pair 211 to 0.21111…

As long as we don't "use up all our natural numbers" when counting our list, we will have enough natural numbers left over to count the irrationals that are not in the list.

So, where does the idea come from, that we must count in numerical order 1,2,3,4,5…? Is it just to make the proof work? Why are we aiming for a bijection when all we need is an injection?

Comment: What do you mean? Usually, in most pairings, you end up using every natural, but not every irrational. So, the naturals are "complete" in your words, but the irrationals are not.

Comment: If you have an infinite set of natural numbers, then you can find a bijection of that set with the entirety of the natural numbers. So injection and bijection are the same.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila If you have an infinite set of irrational numbers, and you can find an injection of that set with the set of natural numbers, then there is a bijection between the irrationals and naturals. So injection and bijection are the same in this case. Look up Schröder–Bernstein.

Comment: Really? You sending me to learn basic set theory? With the exception of your false inference, how is this different between what I said? Note that *a* set of irrational numbers is not *the* set of irrational numbers (which would be the set of *all* irrational numbers). The empty set is *a* set of irrational numbers, but it is not *the* set of irrational numbers.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Sorry about sending you. We have mapped all the irrationals on the list, and all the irrationals not on the list that we can create by changing digits. What other irrationals are we missing?

Comment: Add that new one to your list, and run the algorithm again. You'll find another one that's missing. The proof shows that ***any*** function from $\Bbb N$ to the irrationals is missing something. It's not hard to find a function that misses *some* irrational number, $n\mapsto n+\sqrt2$, for example. Then Cantor's diagonal shows it misses *an* irrational number, does that mean that once we've added that one we're done and covered the whole set?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila We do have irrational numbers not on the list, but we also have natural numbers not on the list, and the numbers not on the list seem to balance. We have the same amount of irrationals not on the list as we have natural numbers not on the list.

Comment: @AsafKaragila When I saw OP refer you to Schröder–Bernstein, I legitimately started cracking up of laughter. This is quality meme material.

Comment: OP, since your list is missing both naturals and irrationals, that means that your list doesn't show anything. You haven't made any claims about the amount of irrationals you missed vs the number of naturals you've missed, because you have no way of knowing. As such, you need to adopt a new approach (i.e., Cantor's approach)

Answer (score 3):

Cantor's diagonal proof concludes that there is no *bijection* from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This is why we must count every natural: if there was a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, it would have to take care of $1, 2, \cdots$ and so on. We can't skip any, because of the very definition of a bijection. You're misunderstanding the proof: you can't consider an incomplete list, because what the proof is trying to prove is exactly that there's no way to list **all** of the natural numbers to all of the real numbers in a bijective manner.

Comment: We don't need "the very definition of a bijection" we only need an injection from the irrationals to the naturals.

Comment: @PaulBunyan as others have answered, that's impossible too, again by the diagonal argument. Eventually you'll have "used up" all the naturals and still have irrationals left over.

Comment: At the rate I am going I will use up only $\frac{n}{10^n}$ natural numbers, leaving me with $\frac{10^n-n}{10^n}$ numbers unused.

Comment: You're thinking too "finitely". What I meant, more precisely, is that while you're going about this one number at a time to construct your list, using Cantor's diagonal argument I can just take all the numbers in your list and from there construct one that's left over, so your list is "incomplete". I suggest you read the proof more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Your example does not show that Cantor's proof fails, because the proof you have given is not Cantor's proof. In Cantor's argument, we **do** assign a real to every natural number.

I'm not sure if you are suggesting the result itself is wrong, but if so, then this isn't the case anyway: just because you have presented an incorrect proof (though I would rather say an "incomplete" proof, as it's easy to fix) does not mean that there is no correct proof.

And as to your question "why can we not count by skipping numbers?" - no reason at all, we can do exactly that, as long as you can find some contradiction which proves the theorem.  On the other hand, it's just as in my previous paragraph - if you can't find a proof using this method, it doesn't mean the theorem can't be proved by a different method.

Comment: David said "we do assign a real to every natural number." I think it is the other way around, we assign a natural to every irrational on the list. Then we find an irrational not on the list and conclude there are more irrationals, since we "used up all our naturals". By my method we use only a small fraction of the naturals counting our list of irrationals, so we will have plenty of unused naturals.

Comment: That is not correct.  I think you must have misread Cantor's proof.  What you are describing is the way you did it, not the way Cantor did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily apply Cantor's diagonal argument to the list you provided. Just build an infinite decimal that doesn't match the $1$st position in the number you paired with $1$, the $17$th position in the number you paired with $17$, and so on. No need to think of those integers in order. The number you've built can't be paired with anything.

As long as you use infinitely many natural numbers in your list you don't have to use them all. The argument shows that but you can't have used every infinite decimal. So the list of infinite decimals can't be "complete" (a word which you have not actually defined).

You can't fix the list by using one of the natural numbers I left out to pair with that new number - because you can adjust the appropriate place in the "new number" to find something not on the list.

Comment: Obviously, that's the diagonal argument, but I don't think this answers the OP's misunderstanding. OP doesn't really understand how injections and surjections work.

Comment: @DonThousand Perhaps. I read the question as thinking the diagonal argument failed if you skipped some natural numbers.

Comment: Ethan said "The number you've built can't be paired with anything." It can be paired with 16, since the 16 was not used.

Comment: @PaulBunyan Try to pair it with $16$. Then  change it's value in the $16$th place and _that_ number isn't paired. Doesn't matter how many gaps there are in the natural number sequence. You can always build a number not paired.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker, now you are just moving the goal posts.

Answer (score 0):

"As long as we don't 'use up all our natural numbers' when counting our list, we will have enough natural numbers left over to count the irrationals that are not in the list."

You are correct that if you don't "use up" the natural numbers in making a list of irrationals, you will end up with some naturals not in the list. Now, where do you prove that all of the irrationals are in it? Or are you just assuming that part?

But if your list is infinite, then you can make a bijection between *all* of the naturals, and the ones you did use. From that bijection and what you are calling an injection (more below), you can make a bijection between *all* of the naturals and the irrationals you listed. Finally, you can use that bijection in diagonalization, and find an irrational you didn't list.

But:
A *function* maps each member of the domain to one member of the co-domain.

In *injection* is a *function* that maps never maps different members of the domain to the same member of the co-domain.

A *surjection* is a *function* that maps at least one members of the domain to every member of the co-domain.

By skipping natural numbers, and not proving you have every irrational, you don't make a function. Let alone an injection.

+++++

Here's a simple outline of Cantor's Proof, which is almost always misrepresented. Let |R1 be the set of reals in [0,1]:

1) Let f be any function f:|N->|R1.

2) Use diagonlization to construct, from f, a real number r in |R1 that is not mapped by the function f.

3) Conclude that if f exists, it cannot be a surjection.

4) Conclude that a bijection, which by definition must be a surjection, is impossible.

Note that "contradiction" and "injection" do not appear, and are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we pair up all natural numbers, we can create an irrational one that won't be on the list, we can order them by which natural number number they are paired up with. the one paired up with 1 is 1st, the one paired up with 2 is 2nd etc. Cantors argument is basically even after reaching transfinite ordinals, you can make a new irrational number that will not be on that list.